# Float and Clear Images

Tags: html, css

Why does an image do not clear (i.e. go below) after a previously floated image?

Let us say

```
 .floatclass {float:right}
 .clrclass {clear:right}

<img class="floatclass" src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84">
<img class="clrclass" src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84">
```

Comment: This is what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/9380omfb/

Comment: w3 docs says that if you clear succeeding element to the direction of previous float then succeeding element should go below the floated element. That works for non image elements but why not images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because images are default `display: inline;` Make it `display: block;` will work for you.

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9380omfb/1/)**

Comment: ketan, so it means you inlines can't be cleared only blocks?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Also read good explanation. http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

HTML Code

```
<img class="floatclass" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/jTx/oX6/jTxoX6nXc.gif" width="95" height="84">
<img class="clrclass" src="http://orig06.deviantart.net/d56b/f/2011/210/7/f/mortal_kombat_logo_gif_2_by_artchell-d420krj.gif" width="95" height="84">
```

CSS Code

```
.floatclass {float:right; display: block;}
.clrclass {clear:right; display: block;}
```